# Nginx rewrite or redirect for subfolder

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I have a Debian 10 server with NGINX. And it is servering several domains. Let me explain the situation:

- I have setup my HTTP redirects permanently to HTTPS, in a file called redirect.conf. It is responsible for redirecting for all http to https domains. That works beautifully. So if anyone goest to http://host.domain.com it redirects to https://host.domain.com. NO PROBLEMS there.
- I am now trying to setup a secondary redirection to subfolder, for only ONE SPECIFIC DOMAIN, but that keeps failing. The browser keeps telling me too many redirects.

I would very much like the following to happen:

1. In browser you type the URL ==> http://host.domain.com OR https://host.domain.com
2. You get redirected to https://host.domain.com (WORKS GREAT)
3. Further redirects to https://host.domain.com/subfolder (FAILS HERE - Browsers complaint too many redirects).

Is there a better way of doing this? As I said in (1) above, whether you enter http or https, I would like the end result for that particular domain to go to /subfolder.

Here is my code for specific domain redirect to subfolder host-domain.conf:

```
server {
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.pem;
  index index.php index.html;
  client_max_body_size 0;
  root /web;
  server_name host.domain.com;

 location / {
    return 301 https://host.domain.com/subfolder/;
  }

}
```

Comment: If you would add a "location /subfolder/", with the necessary directives, there would be no more redirects once the client requests /subfolder/.

Comment: Could you help me with that a little more. I mean would I add that where the code has location /? so instead, I will put location /subfolder/ ?

Comment: What do you want to happen to the requests that are not for /subfolder/ ?

Comment: so for this specific domain, I have a specific host. Only for that host, I want it to go to that subfolder. Currently I can easily go to http => host.domain.com/subfolder, and it redirects me to https => host.domain.com/subfolder.... I'm trying to set it up that the user doesn't have to put the /subfolder/ in the URL. Again, it is ONLY for this specific HOST and DOMAIN.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
location / {
  return 301 https://host.domain.com/subfolder$uri;
}

location /subfolder/ {
  try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html =404;
}
```

Comment: Ok just tested it. Now I'm getting the funniest error. The URL in the Browser is CORRECT. Perfect, but the browser is showing 404 not found //

Comment: Perhaps there's nothing accessible in /web/subfolder ?

Comment: There is, so I can go to that URL directly. That's the strange part. So if I disable this .conf file. Restart NGINX. ANd then go to http ==> host.domain.com/subfolder/ ... it takes me to https ==> host.domain.com/subfolder/.... no issues ..everything loads. My goal is for end user not to enter the /subfolder/ everytime at the end of their URL

Comment: You don't forget to clean your browser's cache?

Comment: I notice "index.php" in your config.  Is PHP involved in your tests?

Comment: Yes, I always clear the cache. The browser is setup to delete all cache at close.

Comment: Yes, there is PHP. But I can load host.domain.com/subfolder/index.php OR index.html. It works either way

Comment: It's just that the try_files may cause problems for fastcgi directives.

Comment: So, currently, a request for https://host.domain.com/index.php results in https://host.domain.com/subfolder/index.php which gives 404 ?

Comment: Surely, you left out that part of your config dealing with the PHP ?

Comment: Hi again, yes, so if I put http = host.domain.com it goes to ===> https = host.domain.com/subfolder. So what do we need for PhP here? Do we need different coding / parameters? I'm not very apt at this.

Comment: What do you have in your current config for PHP?

Comment: Hmmm... that might be a little tricky for me. Do I just open the index.php file and show you that?

Comment: No way.  A question first:  did you install php-fpm?   If not, read and follow a couple of howto's, eg. https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/serve-php-php-fpm-and-nginx/  or  https://tecadmin.net/install-nginx-php-fpm-centos-8/ or search them with duckduckgo.com.

Comment: Yes, so I installed the php-fpm and it is running ofcourse. I looked at that document. And logically it seems to be aligned. What I don't understand is that my HTTP to HTTPS forwarding works. Why does this one become recursive or 404 not found.

Comment: Can you complete your configuration in your original question?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate? Complete my configuration? What part should I add. Do you need the index.php file, or do you need the .conf file which has the HTTP to HTTPS redirection? The file i put in the original question is the one for doing /subfolder redirection.

Comment: I need to see that part of the .conf which handles PHP (the connection to php-fpm).